# Form layout breaks when J script error message div displays

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I created a form with error messages appearing in divs. They work fine. However when the error message appears in the div, my form creates a line break after the the div below the relevant label and form field. Is there a way through css or Jscript to rectify this?

I have the exact same form without the error appearing in the div, but appearing below the label and no line break happens. I don't know Jscript at all. Just a web designer winging it with JavaScript basic knowledge from 10 years ago. So simple explanations with actual code snippets would be a great help.

This is my script for the form with the error in a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#account-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            errorElement: 'div',
            // your other rules and options
     });

        });
</script>
```

This is the error style:

```
<style>
    div.error { background-color:#CE5454; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;; color:#FFF;     display: inline-block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:0.9em; font-weight:normal; text-align:center; margin:0 0 0 20px; padding:3px 10px; position:relative; white-space: pre; z-index: 5000; float: left; top:-30px; left:430px;}

    div.error::after{ content:''; display:block; height:0; width:0; border-color:transparent #CE5454 transparent transparent; border-style:solid; border-width:11px 10px; position:absolute; left:-19px; top:0;}

    input.error { border: 1px solid #CE5454;}
</style>
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="#" id="account-form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>My account</legend>
            <div>           
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" minlength="5" maxlength="12" class="required"/>
            </div>

            <div>   
            <label for="password">Password <span class="asterix">*  </span></label>
            <span class="tooltip_help" title="Your password must be between 5-10 characters and include at least one number">?</span>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="5" maxlength="10" class="required my_password_validation"/>

            </div>

            <div>           
            <label for="password">Confirm Password <span class="asterix">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" name="confirmPass" id="confirmPass" minlength="5" maxlength="10" class="required c_password" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>About Me</legend>
            <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="ex. John King"/>
            </div>

            <div>
            <label for="email">Email <span class="asterix">*</span></label>
            <span class="tooltip_help" title="Remember to include the '&#64;' sign and '&#46;' for your email to be valid">?</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@email.com" class="required email"/>                   
            </div>

            <div>
            <label for="emailConfirm">Confirm Email <span class="asterix">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" name="emailConfirm" id="emailConfirm" placeholder="name@email.com" class="required email" equalTo='#email'/>
            </div>


        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

        <ul>
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tos" value="tos" class="required" />
            <label for="tos">Click here to accept our terms of service <span class="asterix">*</span></label>
            <div style="float: right; position: relative; top: -5px;">
                <span class="tooltip_help" title="You must accept our terms of service to proceed">?</span>
            </div>          
            </li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign me up!"/>
        </p>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

Comment: [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ4bA/), it was your positioning properties for `div.error` that was causing your layout to break.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need it to display on the right, outside of the form. That's why I used the code you commented out `float: left; top:-30px; left:430px;` With this code the error div is displayed in the correct position, but an empty line break appears under the label and input field, breaking the design of my form. So is there a way of keeping the position and losing the line break?

Comment: OMG I can't believe it. I found the answer.  John Klakegg helped me clarify the question in my head. I used some code I had for my tool tip and adjusted the css accordingly. Since I am not allowed to post an answer I'll do it in a comment.

Comment: So, here is what I did.

For J script:

   `$('#account-form').validate({ errorElement: 'div', position: "center right", offset: [8,15] });`

Comment: And for CSS:

I removed the following code from `div.error` as John Klakegg pointed out:

    `float: left; top:-30px; left:430px;` 

In `div.error` I also changed the position from relative to absolute and increased the margin from 20px to 120px:

Comment: `div.error { background-color:#CE5454; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; color:#FFF; display: inline-block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:0.9em; font-weight:normal; text-align:center; margin:0 0 0 120px; padding:3px 10px; position:absolute; white-space: pre; z-index: 5000; }`

Comment: Glad you got it working :)